# When creating a object from a model. the object is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

Hello for a project i need to log the export of .csv downloads.
I have searched a lot but still cannot find the answer.

I created a collection: 'tokens' in my mongoDB

- The model is located in /src/models/token.coffee
- the app is located in /src/app.coffee
- controller located in /src/controllers/token.coffee

This is my model:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')
timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp')
enums = require './enums'
schema = mongoose.Schema

# Schema definition
TokenSchema = new schema
  user:
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: 'User'
    required: true
  first_name:
    type: String
    required: true
  last_name:
    type: String
    required: true
  status:
    type: String
    enums: enums.TokenStatuses.__values
    default: enums.TokenStatuses.running

# Plugins
TokenSchema.plugin timestamps, createdAt: 'created_at',  updatedAt: 'changed_at'

try
  mongoose.model 'Token', TokenSchema
```

i call the following function from the controller:

```
create_tokens_record = (user_id) ->
  User.findOne {_id: user_id}, (err, user) ->
   obj =
   user: user._id
   first_name: user.first_name
   last_name: user.last_name

   token = new models.Token(obj)
   console.log token
   token.save (err) ->
      return err if err
```

And the error is:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at c:\Users\Daan\api\src\controllers\user.coffee:239:15
    at Query.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Daan\api\src\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3435:16)
    at c:\Users\Daan\api\src\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:273:21
    at c:\Users\Daan\api\src\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:492:13)
```

I have no idea why my model is still undefined. Hope anyone can help me out!

Comment: What's the line of code in user.coffee:239??

Comment: @Subburaj, I found out that on some parts the line of code is not correct in the error log.
But i found out that it is happening on this line:

 token = new models.token(obj)

Note: i require the model as this: models = require '.,/models'
i tried requiring it with: 

Token = require './models/token'

And then create the model with: token = new Token(obj)
Got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

In my project there was a index.coffee where all the models were exported.
I forgot to add the newly created model to this file.